# Why would countries ever fight over who gets an alien object?

Tags: internal-consistency

A Lot of recent plots in SF resolve around the USA trying to beat Russia or China (or whoever the current US boogieman of the moment is!) to an alien artefact, star ship, whatever.

Considering how bad US Security is wouldn't it be more prudent to let the USA Spend the money to recover the artefact and just wait for the technology to leak out or would the technological advantage be so much that the current MAD (mutually assured destruction) balance in place would make getting the object or a first strike a realistic solution?

Just curious on some realistic thoughts

Comment: I'd say it depends a lot on which country is trying to recover it. The US or a country that's at least semi-reasonable trying to get it is one thing, but I think we can all agree that no one is gonna let, say, North Korea get their  hands on something that has even the smallest chance of being world changing.

Comment: Consider whether US security really is bad, or whether leaks of really unimportant stuff are made in order to create the impression that it's bad.  That way, when country X stumbles upon the lightly-secured plans for secret weapon Y, they never stop to think that the plans have several carefully-engineered flaws that will keep it from ever working right.  So X's dictator thinks the fault is their incompetent engineers and executes a bunch, leaving them short of engineering talent...

Comment: Even if US security *in general* is bad (let's just assume that's true), it's unlikely that thier security around a **recently recovered alien artifact** will be bad. They'll drop that thing at the bottom of Cheyenne Mountain and cover it in ten stories of military, then form a wall of tanks around the mountain.  Maybe another nation will be able to sneak it and steal it in ten years, after the presidency has changed at least once and the public have begun to forget about "that alien thing," but by then the US will have reaped untold rewards from studying it.

Answer (score 3):

I think with questions like these it helps to consider it as an extreme and work your way backwards.

**If your spies are good enough to get tech eventually, why does anyone bother with their own research?**

The answer, I believe, comes in the form of the [first-mover advantages](http://study.com/academy/lesson/first-mover-advantages-disadvantages-examples.html). There are many reasons but the one that most applies to your question is: If you get there first you have time to find your feet first.

As with most, it is one thing to see it on paper and another to do it. The Russians might steal some written reports but if the US have engineers who have been getting inside the machine and not necessarily writing down every little detail the US have an advantage.

In war, every advantage counts.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that they are trying to prevent their enemies from getting the technology. We trust ourselves to make the right decisions when faced with responsibility, but do we trust our enemies?

The artefact can be stored in an extremely secure facility that lets no one in or out.
Reverse engineering it is optional.

Also, if the technology is reverse engineered, it can also be done so in a secure way, where all engineers/scientist are kept on site and surveyed very closely.
Actually implementing the technology, again, is optional. If the research never leaves the secure facility then espionage is highly improbable. It's only once you start manufacturing something that people can try to sneak a peek at the designs.